# CSS, hover box over image only appearing on ONE image

Tags: html, css

I have successfully coded a hover color and text over an image.  I would like to duplicate that for the remaining three images.  Right now, the code executes successfully for the first image, but none of the rest.  What am I doing wrong?  Thank you.  The code is as follows:

```css
/* lily pad positioning */

#link1 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  height: auto;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

#link2 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  height: auto;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 55px;
}

#link3 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  height: auto;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#link4 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  height: auto;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}


/* lily pad positioning */


/* image hover css */

#hover1 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #234d20;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#overlay1 {
  background: rgba(119, 171, 89, .85);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

#box1:hover #overlay1 {
  opacity: 20;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
}


/* BOX TWO */

#hover2 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #234d20;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#overlay2 {
  background: rgba(119, 171, 89, .85);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

#box2:hover #overlay2 {
  opacity: 20;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
}


/* BOX THREE */

#hover3 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #234d20;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#overlay3 {
  background: rgba(119, 171, 89, .85);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

#box3:hover #overlay3 {
  opacity: 20;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
}


/* BOX FOUR */

#hover4 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #234d20;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#overlay4 {
  background: rgba(119, 171, 89, .85);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

#box4:hover #overlay4 {
  opacity: 20;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav_box">
  <!--nav box open-->
  <div id="box1">
    <img id="link1" src="lilypad.png" alt="lilypad">
    <div id="overlay1">
      <span id="hover1">Hello!!!</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="box2">
    <img id="link2" src="lilypad.png" alt="lilypad">
    <div id="overlay2">
      <span id="hover2">Hello!!!</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="box3">
    <img id="link3" src="lilypad.png" alt="lilypad">
    <div id="overlay3">
      <span id="hover3">Hello!!!</span>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="box4">
    <img id="link4" src="lilypad.png" alt="lilypad">
    <div id="overlay4">
      <span id="hover4">Hello!!!</span>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
<!--nav box close-->
```

Comment: Its hitting more than one, try changing `Hello!!!` to a different string for each one to see what you are hitting when

Comment: Ok, I tried that and now when I hover over images 2-4, the text changes, but the hover + text are only appearing over the first image. What might that indicate?

Comment: Inconsitencies in styling. Check you css and make sure everything is aligned correctly.

Comment: also you have height declared twice for each `link` id selector.  It's either a fixed # of pixels or it's auto.  Shouldn't be both. And you can shorten your padding CSS to a single line if you want `padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;`

Comment: Ran the css through a validator and fixed all errors.  changed "link id" padding to just pixels, no auto.  still no dice!

Comment: Please just post relevant text in your future questions @pandasalad you have to keep in mind there are very busy people on this website trying to help others. When posts 'look' long they tend to be overlooked very quickly. Just get straight to the point and you'll have more success with helpers!

Comment: @soulshined the website would not let me post without adding more garbage! it said i had too much code and not enough text!  XD

Comment: ohhh i get it now @pandasalad that's funny. I thought you were talking about another website you used to code it in. my apologies

Answer (score 0):

Set `position:relative` on each overlay parent.

Since your hover overlays are set to `position:absolute`, breaking them out of the page flow, there needs to be some parent element above them with `position:relative`. The positioning of absolute elements is determined by the closest *relative* element in the HTML structure. If nothing in the HTML structure is set to relative, the browser will go with the entire document window, which the means the hover overlays all appear along the left edge of the browser.

In any case, you're over-using id's; it's inefficient. You should make use of classes, it's the most fundamental thing to understand about CSS. In practice you may not ever need such fine-grained id's and probably someone could make a case about performance if you're bogging the browser down in the case of 1000's of elements.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/MarsAndBack/pen/VgJvbz)

```css
#nav_box {
  display: flex;
}

.link {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  height: auto;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  position: relative;
}


.label {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #234d20;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.overlay {
  background: rgba(119, 171, 89, .85);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

.box:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 20;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav_box">

  <div id="box1" class="box">
    <img class="link" src="lilypad.png" alt="lilypad">
    <div class="overlay">
      <span class="label">Hello 111!!!</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="box2" class="box">
    <img class="link" src="lilypad.png" alt="lilypad">
    <div class="overlay">
      <span class="label">Hello 222!!!</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="box3" class="box">
    <img class="link" src="lilypad.png" alt="lilypad">
    <div class="overlay">
      <span class="label">Hello 333!!!</span>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="box4" class="box">
    <img class="link" src="lilypad.png" alt="lilypad">
    <div class="overlay">
      <span class="label">Hello 444!!!</span>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
<!--nav box close-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Your css is identical for each of the four link ids and associated overlays: you should therefore use **classes** instead of **ids**. This will greatly reduce your code. I have adjusted your code to use classes, but I left the box1:hover .overlay{} /box2 etc.. css (at the end) as you may want display boxes with different opacity on hover/of different sizes etc. I adjusted the `text` and `alt text` so that you can see which one is which (as the images don't display in the snippet), and added in a `background-color` to one the `box2:hover` just to illustrate that if you want to adjust the colour of the box on hover, you can make the modifications in the :hover css.

Do note that you can use more than one class. I created separate classes for the margin css (.l1 and .l2). You can adjust these as needsbe, and/or create more if necessary

Hope this helps!

(p.s. I  floated them to the right instead of the left, just for the hover demo, but you can change this back of course)

```css
/* lily pad positioning */

.lilylink {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative; 
  vertical-align:top;
  float:right;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  height: auto;
  padding:10px;
}

.l1 {
  margin-left: 35px;
}

.l2 {
  margin-right: 55px;
}


/* lily pad positioning */


/* image hover css */

.hovering {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #234d20;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.overlay {
  background: rgba(119, 171, 89, .85);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#box1:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 20;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
}


/* BOX TWO */

#box2:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 20;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
  background-color:blue;
}


/* BOX THREE */

#box3:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 20;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
}


/* BOX FOUR */

#box4:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 20;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav_box">
  <!--nav box open-->
  <div id="box1">
    <img class="lilylink l1" src="lilypad.png" alt="lilypad 1">
    <div class="overlay">
      <span class="hovering">Hello!!!</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="box2">
    <img class="lilylink l2" src="lilypad.png" alt="lilypad 2">
    <div class="overlay">
      <span class="hovering">Hello 2</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="box3">
    <img class="lilylink l1" src="lilypad.png" alt="lilypad 3">
    <div class="overlay">
      <span class="hovering">Hello 3</span>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="box4">
    <img class="lilyink l2" src="lilypad.png" alt="lilypad 4">
    <div class="overlay">
      <span class="hovering">Hello 4</span>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
<!--nav box close-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block` instead of the floats. In the snippet below I overwrote your settings by using the following rule which applies to box1, 2, 3 and 4, but you should erase the floats. (The border is just there to make the div areas visible)

```
#nav_box > div {
  border: 1px dotted green; 
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

BTW: You can omit a lot of CSS code if you use combined CSS selectors and classes where the settings of child elements are identical.

```css
/* lily pad positioning */

#link1 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  height: auto;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

#link2 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  height: auto;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 55px;
}

#link3 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  height: auto;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#link4 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  height: auto;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}


/* lily pad positioning */


/* image hover css */

#hover1 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #234d20;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#overlay1 {
  background: rgba(119, 171, 89, .85);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

#box1:hover #overlay1 {
  opacity: 20;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
}


/* BOX TWO */

#hover2 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #234d20;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#overlay2 {
  background: rgba(119, 171, 89, .85);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

#box2:hover #overlay2 {
  opacity: 20;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
}


/* BOX THREE */

#hover3 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #234d20;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#overlay3 {
  background: rgba(119, 171, 89, .85);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

#box3:hover #overlay3 {
  opacity: 20;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
}


/* BOX FOUR */

#hover4 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #234d20;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#overlay4 {
  background: rgba(119, 171, 89, .85);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

#box4:hover #overlay4 {
  opacity: 20;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
}
#nav_box > div {
  border: 1px dotted green; 
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav_box">
  <!--nav box open-->
  <div id="box1">
    <img id="link1" src="lilypad.png" alt="lilypad">
    <div id="overlay1">
      <span id="hover1">Hello 1 !!!</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="box2">
    <img id="link2" src="lilypad.png" alt="lilypad">
    <div id="overlay2">
      <span id="hover2">Hello 2!!!</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="box3">
    <img id="link3" src="lilypad.png" alt="lilypad">
    <div id="overlay3">
      <span id="hover3">Hello 3!!!</span>
    </div>
  </div>

 
  <div id="box4">
    <img id="link4" src="lilypad.png" alt="lilypad">
    <div id="overlay4">
      <span id="hover4">Hello 4!!!</span>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
<!--nav box close-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes in your css and the bellow code should work.

The thing you have to remember is that an element set to absolute will look for a parent that has the position set for relative. So you need to add that to the parent element and also set the position of the absolute element, I used left and right in the example.

Also since the code was repeating a lot I added classes for box, link, hover and overlay, it works because on the hover event it will only modify the child element overlay and not the other ones.

```css
/* box positioning */
.box {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

/* lily pad positioning */

.link { 
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  height: auto;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

/* hover elements */

.hover {
 font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #234d20;
  font-size: 25px;
}

/* overlay elements */

.overlay {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(119, 171, 89, .85);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

/* box hover */

.box:hover .overlay {
  border: 2px solid pink;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav_box">
  <!--nav box open-->
  <div id="box1" class="box">
    <img id="link1" class="link" src="lilypad.png" alt="lilypad">
    <div id="overlay1" class="overlay">
      <span id="hover1"class="hover">Hello!!!</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="box2" class="box">
    <img id="link2" class="link" src="lilypad.png" alt="lilypad">
    <div id="overlay2" class="overlay">
      <span id="hover2"class="hover">Hello!!!</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="box3" class="box">
    <img id="link3" class="link" src="lilypad.png" alt="lilypad">
    <div id="overlay3" class="overlay">
      <span id="hover3"class="hover">Hello!!!</span>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="box4" class="box">
    <img id="link4" class="link" src="lilypad.png" alt="lilypad">
    <div id="overlay4" class="overlay">
      <span id="hover4"class="hover">Hello!!!</span>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
<!--nav box close-->
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are trying to make?

```css
/* lily pad positioning */
#box1{
  display:inline-block;
}
#box2{
  display:inline-block;
}
#box3{
 display:inline-block;
}
#box4{
 display:inline-block;
}
#link1 {
  display: block;
  //float: left;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  height: auto;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

#link2 {
  display: block;
  //float: left;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  height: auto;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 55px;
}

#link3 {
  display: block;
  //float: left;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  height: auto;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#link4 {
  display: block;
  //float: left;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  height: auto;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}


/* lily pad positioning */


/* image hover css */

#hover1 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #234d20;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#overlay1 {
  background: rgba(119, 171, 89, .85);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

#box1:hover #overlay1 {
  opacity: 20;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
}


/* BOX TWO */

#hover2 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #234d20;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#overlay2 {
  background: rgba(119, 171, 89, .85);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

#box2:hover #overlay2 {
  opacity: 20;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
}


/* BOX THREE */

#hover3 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #234d20;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#overlay3 {
  background: rgba(119, 171, 89, .85);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

#box3:hover #overlay3 {
  opacity: 20;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
}


/* BOX FOUR */

#hover4 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #234d20;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#overlay4 {
  background: rgba(119, 171, 89, .85);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

#box4:hover #overlay4 {
  opacity: 20;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav_box">
  <!--nav box open-->
  <div id="box1">
    <img id="link1" src="lilypad.png" alt="lilypad">
    <div id="overlay1">
      <span id="hover1">Hello!!!</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="box2">
    <img id="link2" src="lilypad.png" alt="lilypad">
    <div id="overlay2">
      <span id="hover2">Hello!!!</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="box3">
    <img id="link3" src="lilypad.png" alt="lilypad">
    <div id="overlay3">
      <span id="hover3">Hello!!!</span>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="box4">
    <img id="link4" src="lilypad.png" alt="lilypad">
    <div id="overlay4">
      <span id="hover4">Hello!!!</span>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
<!--nav box close-->
```